# Send Notification From Laravel 5.4 to Angular

Tags: angular, laravel, notifications, laravel-5.4

I am creating an application for backend I have use **Laravel5.4** and for the frontend, I am using **Angular 4**. I want to send a notification to my angular app from laravel after the record is inserted into the database.
I have been searching for a while but find nothing fruitful.

Comment: To send notification we use socket. You can follow foloowing url to implement in your project: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51

Comment: this is good but the same platform is used for backend and as well for the front-end i.e Laravel, my backend is in laravel and the front-end is purely in angular 4